# Putasync 400 Bad Request c# - google APi works

Tags: c#, rest, web

I want to sent a base64pdf, via http put. 
Unfortunatly I get the 400 bad request error.

I tried it with the google rest api and there it worked fine.

```
string finalURL = upURL + pdf.Id + "/signedpdf";
string json = "{ 'base64Pdf' : '" + pdf.Base64Pdf + "' }";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
     var response = await client.PutAsync(finalURL, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        return true;
}
```

It works when I create the Json by Javascriptserializer.

```
        TransferObject to = new TransferObject(pdf.Base64Pdf);

        var json2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(to);
```

Comment: You have to read the response content to see what's the reason behind the 400

Comment: I only get this much info from the Server. At first i thought that because it is a modified pdf, that it won't work. but the same json works in the google api. so i do not know what causes the problem.

Comment: What is the size of your json2? Chances are you may exceed allowed limit for data sent as single request (so, you have to use multi-part approach then, sending the data as sequential chunks).

Answer (score 0):

I believe [the JSON standard](https://www.json.org/) only supports **double quote** characters. Your code is using single quote characters in your concatenated JSON. Base64 encoded string will not contain double quote characters so you should be good there. Try this:

```
string json = "{ \"base64Pdf\" : \"" + pdf.Base64Pdf + "\" }";
```